# How do I solve $\left|X\right|\left|Y\right|-X\cdot Y\le\left|X-Y\right|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, calculus-of-variations

a) Derive the inequality

$\left|X\right|\left|Y\right|-X\cdot Y\le\left|X-Y\right|^2$

(Hint: Show that $\left|X\right|\left|Y\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left(X^2+Y^2\right)$and add $\frac{1}{2}\left|X-Y\right|^2$to the right
side of this last inequality.)

(b) Use the result of part (a) to verify that

$\left|\frac{X}{\left|X\right|}-\frac{Y}{\left|Y\right|}\right|\le\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{\left|X\right|\left|Y\right|}}\left|X-Y\right|$

How do I use Cauchy inequality to solve this inequality?

I have no idea.

Comment: Use the hint. $0\le (X\pm Y)^2=X^2\pm 2XY+Y^2$.

Comment: Are $X, Y$ vectors?

Comment: Actully $ X,Y \in R^d$ and $X,Y\neq\emptyset$